# how to solve single nonlinear algebraic equation in two variables?

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, celestial-mechanics

(I am not a mathematician; I am having physics background.)

How to solve a **single** **nonlinear** algebraic equation in **two variables**, $x$ and $y$?

(I know that - if there are two variables, one needs two different equations to solve them.)

Equation is this :

$\frac{1}{2} (x^2+y^2) + \frac{2(1-m)}{r_1} + \frac{2m}{r_2} = C$

where
$m$ and $C$ are constants and $x,y$ are two variables and

where

$r_1 = \sqrt {(x-x_1)^2+y^2}$  and

$r_2 = \sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+y^2}$

and where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constants - i.e. two fixed values of variable $x$.

Is it possible to solve this equation analytically; if not, how to solve it numerically?

Basically my intention is to find all those $(x,y)$ points in $x-y$ plane such that LHS of this equation becomes RHS i.e. constant $C$;  and that is what is the solution is.

IMPORTANT : This equation is from Forest Ray Moulton's a classic and a great book on celestial mechanics, which was published in 1914. That time there were no computers. Still author has drawn the contours (i.e. solution of this equation) in his book ! Its really amazing. My second intention behind this post is that how Moulton did this ?

Comment: What do you need ? $y(x)$ or $x(y)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I need y(x).

Comment: @atom The equation can be brought to an algebraic form of degree $16$ in $x,y$, though it's [not pretty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bu+v%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29+%2B+4+v%281-m%29+%2B+4+u+m+-+2+c+u+v%2C+u%5E2+-+%28x-a%29%5E2+-+y%5E2%2C+v%5E2+-+%28x-b%29%5E2+-+y%5E2%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%7D%5D) and certainly not solvable analytically. As far as numerical approximations and graphs, never underestimate the insight and hard work they would put into it centuries ago.

Comment: One can compute the $C$ values on a grid, then find the points for a specific $C$ on the grid lines, connect them (via mechanical splines?), when uniqueness is in doubt locally refine the grid, then use Newton or gradient descent or just local grid refinement or ...  to correct the curves. So essentially how you would get a contour plot.

Comment: Fix a value $y$, numerically solve the equation by hand (using e.g midpoint method) for $x$, plot the point on the plane. Repeat this for a few other points. Connect the dots.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53232/16685